# Mass subset record objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, node.js, d3.js

I am looking for the most efficient way to extract a subset of elements from a javascript object. Suppose I have many records in the form of javascript objects

```
var records = [
  { foo: 123, bar: 456, baz: 789, boo: [1,2,3] },
  { foo: 345, bar: 754, baz: 853, boo: [4,3,2] },
  { foo: 321, bar: 234, baz: 443, boo: [5,2,1] }
]
```

And for each of these objects I want to extract the same keys, which are stored in an array, e.g.

```
var keys = ["bar", "boo"]
```

The native way to do so would be along the lines of

```
out = [];
for(var i = 0; i < records.length; i++){
  out[i] = {};
  for(var j = 0; j < keys.length; j++){
    var field = keys[j];    
    out[i][field] = records[i][field]
  }
}
console.log(out)
```

Is there a faster / more elegant way?

Comment: What is the purpose of this? There's no harm in having extra properties.

Comment: I am using this with crossfilter.js. My dataset is quite large (thousands of records). I don't want to allocate more memory than necessary.

Comment: Well you're already allocating the memory to have the object in the first place, and then you're practically doubling it as you create another object with all those records.

Comment: The records are emitted by the csv 1 by 1 by the csv parser, and not stored afterwards, so I assume the garbage collector gets rid of them pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about speed, but a more concise notation could be (assuming all keys are present in each record):

```
var out = records.map(function(v) {
  return keys.reduce(function(o, k) {
    return (o[k] = v[k], o);
  }, {});
});
```

Comment: I like this solution. Good use of map/reduce.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a better Big O notation for your problem, but looking at the current data, a good algoritm may not be your primary focus?

In ECMA-script 5 the base Object contains a keys method:

```
a = {a: '1', b: '2', c: '3'}
Object.keys(a)
// [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
```